# Can I use wildcards in python setup.cfg?

Tags: python

I have a `setup.cfg` configuration script in which I list a bunch local files to be installed, i.e. like following:

```
[files]
packages = tests
           utils

scripts = utils/Communication.ComModule.dll
    utils/Communication.DeployerLib.Controls.dll
    utils/Communication.DeployerLib.dll
    utils/Communication.RModule.Data.dll
    utils/Communication.RModule.dll
    utils/Communication.Serial.dll
    utils/Components.dll
    utils/Converters.dll
    utils/Data.dll
    utils/Log.dll
    utils/Log.Log4Net.dll
    ....
```

So instead of listing every single file, can I use a wildcard in order to install every `dll` file? Is this possible? Can I just use something like the following (to install all `dll` and all `exe`)?

```
[files]
packages = tests
           utils

scripts = utils/*.dll
    utils/*.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it seems that currently neither wildcards/globbing nor something like the `find:`  directives is supported for `scripts` key (https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html). So I don't see any other option as listing all scripts or switch back to `setup.py`.

However, given you want to ship `.dll` files living within our package, one of the following alternatives might be worth considering:

```ini
[options]
packages = utils
zip_safe = False

[options.package_data]
* = *.dll
    *.exe
```

or

```ini
[options]
include_package_data = True
zip_safe = False
```

(the latter requires to have a `MANIFEST.in` containing the file patterns to include). See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html for details. If you later need to locate a `.dll` installed that way from within your `utils` Python module, use something like

```py
from pathlib import Path
package_path = Path(__file__).parent
dll_name = str(package_path / "Communication.Serial.dll")
```

or, for newer Python versions, use the functionality from `importlib`.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you add the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module. Example:

```
import glob

wildcard_path = "/some/directory/*.dll"

file_list = glob.glob(wildcard_path)
```

The variable `file_list` will now be a list of all the *.dll files in /some/directory. So put your wildcard path in the config file and use glob to retrieve the actual file names.

Keep in mind that you'll need to be careful how you enter paths in the config file though. I would recommend using absolute paths in the config file so your results are consistent no matter where you run the script from. If you pass a relative path to glob, it will look for that path from the current working directory.

Comment: The example you have given is valid python path, but the config file is a cfg file and does not contain python code. Therefore, I am still not sure how to change the content of the cfg file.

Comment: Do you mean that you can only edit the config file and that someone else's code is parsing it? It that's the case it depends on how the coder wrote the script doing the parsing. You'll have to ask them.

Comment: I assume you refer to the script `setup.py`, which parses the `setup.cfg` file? Then I totally forgot about that script - and I have to talk to colleagues (or take a look myself at that script). In that case, your suggestion makes absolute sense...